# How do you allow implicit type parameter and provide const parameters?

Tags: rust

In the following, how do you specify ENABLED, but let T be inferred from the val argument? In the following, I have to specify i32.

```rust
fn func_with_const_if<T, const ENABLED: bool>(val: &T)
where T: std::fmt::Debug {
  if ENABLED {
    println!("val: {:?}", val);
  }
}

pub fn main() {
  let val: i32 = 5;
  func_with_const_if::<i32, true>(&val);
}
```

If I put ENABLED before T, I get the following:

```
help: reorder the parameters: lifetimes, then types, then consts
```

Comment: You can use an underscore (`_`) as a placeholder for types you want the compiler to infer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To leave a generic parameter inferred when you need to specify other parameters, use the `_` placeholder:

```rust
    func_with_const_if::<_, true>(&val);
```

(Reordering the parameters wouldn't help even if it were allowed. It'd enable *default* type parameters, but that's specifying a particular default type, not making it be inferred.)